# How to use a second database for user authentication in Symfony2?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

In my Symfony 2.0 application, I have to access a second database which contains the user data. Accordingly, I've got two database connections defined in config_*.yml. My approach to this problem was to pretty much duplicate the existing EntityUserProvider and registering it as a service in services.yml like this:

```
services:
    security.user.provider.concrete.acme_provider:
        class: Acme\MyappBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AcmeUserProvider
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, Acme\MyappBundle\Entity\Users, 'username']
```

This works fine so far, except that it provides me with the default entity manager. How can I inject an entity manager which uses the other database connection? I guess that I'll have to set it up as a service, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a specific EntityManager in a service, inject the whole Doctrine Registry as an argument, like this :

```
services:
security.user.provider.concrete.acme_provider:
    class: Acme\MyappBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AcmeUserProvider
    arguments: [@doctrine, Acme\MyappBundle\Entity\Users, 'username']
```

Then, in your service constructor, affect the EntityManager you want to use as a class property :

```
namespace Acme\MyappBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider;

use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
// ....

class AcmeUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;
    // ...

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, $class, $property)
    {
        $this->em = $doctrine->getEntityManager('your_em');
        // ....
    }

    // ....
}
```